# Apache Jackrabbit, connect to localhost through WebDAV protocol

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I am running the standalone server and trying to make a connection:

```
 try {
       Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:8080/server/");

     } catch (RepositoryException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
```

As stated in: http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/RemoteAccess

However, I am getting:

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to access a repository with the following settings: org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: "the locla host"
The following RepositoryFactory classes were consulted:
    org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryFactoryImpl: declined
org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JndiRepositoryFactory: declined
Perhaps the repository you are trying to access is not available at the moment.
```

I have no problem browsing the jackrabbit server with my webrowser.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `jackrabbit-jcr2dav-*.jar` library in your class-path?

From the error report it looks like the `RepositoryFactory` instances consulted do not include `org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2dav.Jcr2davRepositoryFactory` - which is the factory implementation that understands `http:` URLs.

(aside: You you were missing this library, you'll also need to add in it's dependencies - `jackrabbit-spi2dav-*.jar`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct URI to the WebDAV server entry as in you stacktrace it seems not to be the case:

```
Unable to access a repository with the following settings: org.apache.jackrabbit.repository.uri: "the locla host"
```

You should use `"http://localhost:8080/server"`.

Comment: Id did, the forum quote mechanism complained when  http://localhost:8080/server was a part of the quote, hence i changed it. The code is using "http://localhost:8080/server"